# Running stored functions in mongo aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function

I'm trying to store (and use) a function in a mongodb document and I found that doing an insert like this:

```
db.products.insert({
    name: "Some name",
    priceAlgorithm: function () {
        return 1 + 2;
    }
})
```

Results in something like this:

```
{
    name: "Some name",
    priceAlgorithm: {
        code: "function () { return 1 + 2; }"
    }
}
```

I found that `priceAlgorithm` is a BSON representation of a JS function. But I can't seem to find the correct way to run that function.

Running it in an aggregation stage would be optimum as I could potentially `$sort` and `$match` based on that value.But if that isn't possible I can live with running it as a standard JS function, but deffinitely want to avoid using `eval`.

I also did find that storing procedures in a `system` collection is possible (although, I think, deprecated). But I don't see this working for me, as each document can have a completely different algorithm.

Comment: As per the duplicate question, you cannot run JavaScript code or custom functions via the Aggregation Framework (as at MongoDB 3.6). The BSON type for embedding JavaScript functions in documents is intended to round trip data for interpretation by clients (for example, the `mongo` shell) and cannot be used for sorting or matching of server-side results. You could perhaps vivify JavaScript functions in your client code using `eval()`, but that would be a fragile and insecure design approach for determining product prices.

Comment: That question seems more like a part of my question, rather than a duplicate, but anyway.. so there's no proposed way to store an algorithm to run later? As I stated in my question.. `sort` and `match` are not really a must, would be nice, but deffinitely not a must.

Comment: The Aggregation Framework doesn't support custom functions, but as mentioned you could potentially `eval()` a stored JS function in your client code (although you also wanted to avoid `eval`). I wouldn't recommend eval'ing as it leaves your application exposed to potential side effects or security issues from whatever JS code happens to be saved in the document. If you have different pricing rules per product I would look for an approach which embeds a non-executable algorithm description or reference. BSON's JavaScript code type is intended for round-tripping data, not server-side execution.